# After Windows, Ubuntu installation with HD repartiton & reformat fail

Tags: installation, 13.04, server

I had Windows 7 running on a Lenovo SL400 laptop *without* UEFI (double checked) with NTFS/MBR set up. An install of (MD5-checked) Ubuntu 13.04 Server (note that, no GUI) from a flash drive resulted in no boot, no details as to what was going on, just a white blinking underline cursor on a black screen.

I then used a DOS booting flash drive to reformat the hard drive to FAT32, then reinstalled; failed again, same failure.

So, I loaded Bodhi onto the flash drive, used it to wipe the HD with `dd` then ran `badblocks +w` to completely scrub the drive before putting Ubuntu Server 13.04 back on the flash drive and re-reinstalling; failed again.

It happens whether the BIOS is set to AHCI or Compatibility Mode. It happens whether I use LVM or just ext4 & swap directly on the hard drive (500GB WD).

How can I install Ubuntu server successfully?

Here's more detail: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6274751/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by use of the Boot-Repair LiveUSB/CD https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to rewrite the MFT.